Group saved search audit trail entries based on date
I have created a saved search of type 'Saved Search', which basically reports when was the search last updated. I am just trying to report one line per saved search and the last column should show number of updates happened during the day. For example, in the screenshot, the first 3 entries should get picked and it should show the count of 3. I am getting everything else except the count part as it is giving me the total number of rows. How can I add a condition to tell the saved search to look for {date} = max({date})?
Attachments:
Audit entries of the search in question
Results section
I just want to add one more column that shows the count of entries on that date/time. Please advise how this can be achieved.
Thanks in advance


